# prevent tabs to be seen while window reloading

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page which has 4 jquery UI tabs. The first tab just displays a message saying "HELLO".  The 2nd, 3rd and 4th tabs have some html and php scripts running. All the pages are getting displayed properly. But say for example I am executing the php script on the 3rd tab by submitting a button. It does get executed but when the page reloads, I see the first tab flicker for a second and then the 3rd tab gets displayed. Same is the case for all the tabs. The first tab always gets displayed for a seconds and then it goes. Could you please let me know to add some code so that the 1st tab (or the div in which it is written ) is bypassed when other tab executes some php script.

My Javascript is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function()

{
           $("#menu ul li a").click(function(e) {


            e.preventDefault();

            $("#menu ul li a").each(function() {


                    $(this).removeClass("active");

            });

                $(this).addClass("active");
});


$("#menu").tabs({
fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }
});
});
```

My HTML code is as follows :

```
 <div id="menu">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1" onClick="window.location.href='#tab-1';return false;" >Welcome</a></li>

            <li><a href="#tab-2" onClick="window.location.href='#tab-2';return false" title="Decode">Activation Response Generator</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3" onClick="window.location.href='#tab-3';return false" title="Response">Decode Support Key</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab-4" onClick="window.location.href='#tab-4';return false" title="Response">Decode Recovery Key</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div id="tab-1" >
        <div id ="main">

          <div align=center>
     <table style="padding-top:20px;"> <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;"> <img src="Aruba_Networks_newLogo.png " />   </td>
    <br/>
    </div>


          <?php session_start();$user = $_SESSION['usr'];?>
            </br>
         <tr>
         <td> <font size ="6"> <b> <u> Welcome <?php echo $user; ?></u> </b> </font>  </td>
         </br>
         </br>
         <td> <font size ="6"> <b> <u> HAVE A GREAT DAY  </u> </b> </font> </td>
         </br>
         </br>
         <td> <font size ="6"> <b> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </b>  </font></td>
         </tr>




                </div>
                </div>





<div id="tab-2">
                      <div id= "main">

                      SOME HTML SUBMIT BUTTONS AND TEXTBOXES TO DISPLAY OUTPUT WITH PHP RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND 
</div>
</div>

<div id="tab-3">
                      <div id= "main">

                      SOME HTML SUBMIT BUTTONS AND TEXTBOXES TO DISPLAY OUTPUT WITH PHP RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND 
</div>
</div>

<div id="tab-4">
                      <div id= "main">

                      SOME HTML SUBMIT BUTTONS AND TEXTBOXES TO DISPLAY OUTPUT WITH PHP RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND 
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a overlay div.  Put this inside the body for the whole page, or inside a div with `position: relative`.

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/nuEtI)

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed; /* or absolute if inside a div */
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: white;
}
```

At some point, hide that div to show the underlying content.  This would likely be in a document ready handler, or after an AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  $('.overlay').fadeOut();  });
```

---

You can also spice it up, and put a loading message inside the overlay.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <h1>Loading</h1>
</div>

.overlay h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%; /* nearly the center, good enough for a second of visibility */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply FakeRainBrigand. I tried incorporating your suggestions in my code but now its showing loading with my first tab . The loading symbol just got added but it did not help flickering on my first tab. Could you please tell me where exactly in my code should I put my div class . Just before declaring the div for all the tabs right?

Comment: You should put it at the top of the div containing the contents you want covered.  If you are putting it inside an element, you should change it to absolute positioning, though.